# Pass generics to external methods which also use generics

Tags: c#, generics

I'm wrapping a method that uses generics but I'm not understanding how to pass along generics correctly.

I have a `FindAsset` method which should accept a generic type just like the `LoadAsset` does.

```
public T FindAsset<T>(string assetName) {
    T match;

    foreach (AssetBundle bundle in assets) {
        if (bundle.Contains(assetName)) {
            match = bundle.LoadAsset<???>(assetName);
        }
    }

    return match;
}
```

I'm just not sure how I can properly pass the generic type on to `LoadAsset`. That method also has a signature that accepts a `Type` as a parameter, but in that scenario I can't see a way to correctly cast the object.

I'm hoping the usage for this can simply be `myclass.FindAsset<Sprite>(assetName);`

Comment: Isn't T also the type you want to pass to LoadAsset?

Comment: Just pass `T` again, unless you want to use another type?

Answer (score 6):

If I am understanding the question properly, you just need to pass T as below.

```
public T FindAsset<T>(string assetName) {
    T match;

    foreach (AssetBundle bundle in assets) {
        if (bundle.Contains(assetName)) {
            match = bundle.LoadAsset<T>(assetName);
        }
    }

    return match;
}
```

Comment: Ok I tried this but misunderstood the error. I guess normally this would work, but in my case the LoadAsset method isn't completely generic: `The type 'T' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'UnityEngine.AssetBundle.LoadAsset<T>(string)'. There is no boxing or type parameter conversion from 'T' to `UnityEngine.Object'`

Answer (score 3):

If ~T 
(The same Type to be used by the generic parent class) is not the same type you want to pass to LoadAsset
Then you can pass multiple generics:

```
public T FindAsset<T,U>(string assetName) {...

LoadAsset<U>
```

See more info here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need a generic constraint and you can make your code shorter using linq:

```
public T FindAsset<T>(string assetName) 
  where T : UnityEngine.Object
{
    T bundle = assets.FirstOrDefault(bundle => bundle.Contains(assetName));

    return (bundle != null) ? bundle.LoadAsset<T>(assetName) : null;
}
```